# O que significa << em PHP?

Tags: php

Me deparei com o seguinte cálculo sendo atribuído a uma variável

```
(1103515245 * $num + 12345) % (1 << 31)
```

O que significam esses `<<`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

O operador `<<` não só em php, mas em diversas outras linguagens, trata-se de um **Operador bit-a-bit**.

O que ele faz é deslocar o valor a esquerda do operador n vezes, onde n é o valor a direita do operador. (Deslocar para a esquerda obviamente)

Por exemplo:

```
$a = 2 << 3;
// Em binário temos 2 = 0000 0010, deslocando ele 3x
// obtemos 0001 0000, que resulta em 16
echo $a; // 16
```

Se tiver mais dúvidas, pode consultar o manual do php:
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.bitwise.php

Answer (score 3):

Quando o operador da direita é 31, o operador shift-left é usado com um proposito muito especifico: descobrir se o operador da esquerda é par ou impar.

Se for par, o resultado de `par << 31` vai ser 0.
Se for impar, o resultado de `impar << 31` vai ser -2147483648, o valor minimo de tipos inteiros.

```
0
= 0 000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 em binario
= 0 000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 depois de shift left
= 0

1
= 0 000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 em binario
= 1 000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 depois de shift left
= -2147483648

2 =
= 0 000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010 em binario
= 0 000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 depois de shift left
= 0

...

51 =
= 0 000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0011 0011 em binario
= 1 000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 depois de shift left
= -2147483648
```

A logica é fazer shift para a esquerda ate que todos os digitos desaparecam, excepto o menos significativo. Esse digito indica se o numero original é par ou impar.

Nota: por serem "signed integers", o digito em binario mais à esquerda é usado para o sinal positivo ou negativo.

Nota: Esta resposta assume que os inteiros sao representados com 32 bits. Segundo a minha pesquisa, PHP representa os inteiros com 64 bits se o processador suportar instrucoes de 64 bits - nesse caso devera ser feito um shift `<< 63`

Comment: Não conhecia essa ideia de usar o left shift para ver se é par, mas é mais facil (e menos custoso) fazer `($a&1)==0`